# How to get all the filled data in the table in google sheets api?

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Please tell me how in the Google Sheets API you can not manually get the range of the entire table located on a certain sheet.
I have a table in which the number of columns can change, but I still have to get information from it.

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range='???').execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you **sheet.getDataRange()** to get range of the visible data on your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
         spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
         range='Sheet1',
         majorDimension='ROWS').execute()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?